# Override a controller's [Authorize(Roles="X")] filter in an action of that controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

In an MVC app certain controller has access restricted by a role (there is an `Authorize` filter with a role attached to controller). Now the client decided that one of the actions in this controller should be available to all authenticated users (so `AllowAnonymous` filter alone won't do the trick and adding `Authorize` filter after `AllowAnonymous` doesn't work). How do I go about doing that?

In my case I can't really move the action to another controller and dropping the filter on controller and then adding it to all actions, but one doesn't sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AllowAnonymous` filter will make the action ignore all `Authorize` filters, so a quick and dirty solution would be to include the condition directly in the action (in this case checking if the user is authenticated). Finally, if the condition is not met return `HttpUnauthorizedResult`, to retain the default "redirect to login page" behavior.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ActionAvailableToEveryone()
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
    return View();
}
```

There might be better\more elegant solutions to the problem, but changing membership provider or writing a custom filter just for a single action sounds like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the override attributes on the specific action and then apply  a different filter as suggested in this post: [Filter Overrides](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/filter-overrides-in-asp-net-mvc-5)

Worked for me in Web API.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.